# Load post handler is run twice

Tags: python

I have a load_post handler to run some code at startup:

```
@persistent
def update_prefix(scene):
    # some function
    print("chapters Loaded")

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(update_prefix)
```

It works fine with the blender startup file, but when loading a file it runs twice and gives a PyContext error in the console:

chapters Loaded
Read blend: C:\Users\User\Desktop\File.blend
PyContext 'window' not found
PyContext 'window' not found
PyContext 'blend_data' not found
PyContext 'region' not found
PyContext 'area' not found
PyContext 'screen' not found
PyContext 'screen' not found
PyContext 'area' not found
chapters Loaded

How do I get it to only run once or am I missing something?

EDIT:

Even if I just add this to \startup

```
import bpy 
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def update_prefix(scene):
    print("Hello World")

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(update_prefix)
```

I still get:

Hello World
Read blend: C:\Users\User\Desktop\File.blend
Hello World
PyContext 'window' not found
PyContext 'window' not found
PyContext 'blend_data' not found
PyContext 'region' not found
PyContext 'area' not found
PyContext 'screen' not found
PyContext 'screen' not found
PyContext 'area' not found

This isn't even running a function or operator, it's just printing.
I don't have 2 scenes in the .blend.
if update_prefix in bpy.app.handlers.load_post: return doesn't seem to do anything. Shouldn't the console read:

Read blend: C:\Users\User\Desktop\File.blend
Hello World

Comment: Try `if update_prefix in bpy.app.handlers.load_post: return` in your `register()` function.

Comment: In addition, To make sure you are also clearing the previously appended handler when testing,.removing the functions via there names .  `[f for f in bpy.app.handlers.load_pre if f.__name__.startswith("update_prefix")]`  from the handlers ensures no "_hangers on_".  Does _"some function"_ involve context members? (It looks like you are calling an operator from a handler.. do you have two scenes?)  When registering: context is restricted and some members are not available.  Or in the case of running in headless mode from cli, UI members like screen and area will be None.

Comment: I have edited the question to simplify the problem