# How to run some functions in an addon in blender start?

Tags: add-on, startup-file

Is there anybody who know how can I run some functions in an addon in blender start?

Comment: By execute you mean enable? Have you clicked the Save User Settings button on the bottom of the Blender User Preferences window?

Comment: No. I want to run my addon without any button or something like that. I want it to be run when blender opens.

Comment: Juste after you've enabled the addon, have you clicked the Save User Settings button on the bottom of the Blender User Preferences window? You need to do this if you want your addon to run on your next session

Comment: Yes I did it, but that's not what I'm asking for. I want an automatic run just after the user open Blender.

Comment: @Tanguy the confusion stems from the terminology  used in your q.  An addon is never really "exectuted" or "run" as such;. It's registered when enabled.  Consider addons more like modules. Once it's enabled can use the  operators, panels or set up things like keymaps and handlers..   To run some function from your addon on file load,  add a [persistent load (pre or post)  handler](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example) and configure in  your register method. [Similar](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110454/load-post-handler-is-run-twice)

Comment: @Tanguy if [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112568/how-to-execute-an-addon-in-each-blender-restart#comment198384_112569) is your question, [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/112568/edit)  your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @batFINGER You're right, sorry, I'm a begginer in Blender. Your answer is closer to my problem. Thank you.

Comment: if it is your add-on then you can set you shortcut to start Blender with the -p/--python switch `
blender my.blend --python myscript1.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In user preferences choose add-ons tab check the box of the plugin you want to use and hit save user settings in lower left corner.
If the plugin is not enabled next time you open blender then either you are doing something wrong (like, the shortcut of the plugin activation is diffrent than you think or plugin is updated and changed it's interface so it doesn't appears in the same spot as shown in tutorials) or the plugin is glitched.

Try repeating these steps and downloading and using latest version of the plugin.

Comment: I know that... I want to know for example how to create a "suzanne" directly after blender opens.

Comment: you can open Blender, create your Suzanne, then save this scene as your default preset with ctrl U > Save Startup File, when you'll reopen Blender you'll have a Suzanne by default, is it what you want?